# How to make the bottom corners of a TextInputLayout rounded

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-textinputlayout

I am trying to make the bottom corners of a focused filled TextInputLayout rounded. Here's a screenshot of what I want to achieve.

[image]

I am setting the properties **boxCornerRadiusBottomStart** and **boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd** to *4dp* for example, but the bottom corners of the TextInputLayout are then only rounded when it's not focused. As long as it's focused, the corners are not rounded anymore.
Here's a screenshot of what I am seeing now:

[image]

Comment: You can simply add android:background = "@drawable/rounded_corner" to TextInputLayout and create a customized background with gray color and rounded edges

Answer (score 0):

I am beginner to Android development but I'll try to answer and if their are any mistakes please correct me

I would prefer you to create a drawable resource file from base Shape and try to add this:

`<corners android:bottomLeftRadius = "4dp"` 
`android:bottomRightRadius = "4dp" />`